# Get json result from non local server

Tags: jquery, json

I use following code for get json encoded result

```
$.get('localhost/hospital/index/json', function(data) {
   alert(data);
});
```

It is work for localhost URL. But I want get result from external server. I try following example url to do it.

```
$.get('hospitalsystem.dev/index/json', function(data) {
   alert(data);
});
```

But it is not working. Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help with getting Json Format data from external website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142779/help-with-getting-json-format-data-from-external-website)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omitting the `http://` from the URL, as in your code snippet, can prevent the request from working, as shown in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/simonbrown/BQuBr/).

AJAX requests are limited by [Same Origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), meaning that you can only make requests to the same domain. There are three main ways to get around this:

- [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) involves adding an argument to an API to function as a javascript file. [JQuery can](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp) make this as simple as a normal AJAX request. A big problem with this is that it requires you to trust the provider of the API you're calling not to do anything malicious,  such as transmitting cookies back to them.
- [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://enable-cors.org/) is a more elegant solution, but only works [in some browsers.](http://caniuse.com/cors)
- [Creating a proxy](http://ajaxpatterns.org/archive/Cross-Domain_Proxy.php) for AJAX requests works with virtually any API, but adds some additional overhead and having two  requests instead of one for each AJAX request may impact performance.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, you cannot use AJAX to read data from a different domain.

You should modify the server to use JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

Then use JSONP. Because AJAX calls doesn't work when url is on another server.

So what you need to do is read about JSONPand find a way to use it.

That is basically JSON but in the form of js file, like

```
<script language="javascript" src="/js/my.js"></script>
```

just instead `/js/my.js` use your location, there is no other way, believe me.

Use jQuery to dynamically load scripts from different urls and use data returned by them.

Comment: `language="javascript"`? Can we leave HTML 3.2 behind please?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Server capability you can write an proxy script. Your JS ask the proxy to fetch and response the json file.

For Example: [craigslist rss feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695316/craigslist-rss-feed/7067888#7067888)